# Want to call a different Javascript method each time a different option is selected from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box with two options as recent and popular, the requirement is, if I select recent then a call to back-end should go to get the respective response and same should happen for popular too. I have been through many questions asked here but could not find the exact answer I am looking for. My current code look like this

```
<select class="recentOrPopular" name="mostpopular">
<option value="recent">Recent</option>
<option value="popular">Popular</option>
</select>
```

This is the simple html with two options, and the JavaScript is :

```
if($('.recentOrPopular').val('recent')){
    this.myrecentFunction();
    }

$( ".recentOrPopular" ).change(function() {
    if($('.recentOrPopular').val('popular')){
        this.myPopularFunction();
    }
    if($('.recentOrPopular').val('recent')){
        this.myrecentFunction();
    }
});
```

so by default myrecentFunction is getting called initially, but if I am changing the option then both of the if blocks are getting called. the link to sme kind of fiddle is : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zYRkC/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting the value using the [.val(value)](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) instead of reading it comparing

```
$(".recentOrPopular").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'popular') {
        this.myPopularFunction();
    } else if (value == 'recent') {
        this.myrecentFunction();
    }
});
```

using switch

```
$(".recentOrPopular").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    switch (value) {
        case 'popular':
            this.myPopularFunction();
            break;
        case 'recent':
            this.myrecentFunction();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Arun, this worked I tried many things except this one, i will read the jQuery apis clearly next time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.recentOrPopular').val('popular')
```

is use to SET the value, if you want to compare them use

```
if($('.recentOrPopular').val() == 'popular')
```

also, instead of having if() and then if() use if ... else if() this ensure that if first condition meet, second won't execute.

Comment: Or even better - a switch case, so that the OP can add more and more options as the need arises. An if-else construct would become unmanageable after a few items are added.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as

```
 $( ".recentOrPopular" ).change(function() {
    if($('.recentOrPopular').val()=='popular'){
        this.myPopularFunction();
    }
    if($('.recentOrPopular').val()=='recent'){
        this.myrecentFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select class="recentOrPopular" name="mostpopular" id="dropdownPName" >

pName = document.getElementById('dropdownPName');
var value = pName.options[pName.selectedIndex].value;
switch(value)
{
    case 'recent' : //call your function

    case 'popular' : // call your function

}
```

Comment: Not a fan of jQuery I see... Unless there is a specific reason - there is no need to mix native JS and jQuery like this...

Comment: Yes - jQuery is used to prevent the use of `getElementById` and other native JS functions. Why have you selected not to use jQuery here?

Comment: so why use jQuery in the first place?

Comment: Exactly my point. You are mixing native JS and jQuery where there is no need.

Comment: @Lix Thats bullshit, you can use both and many developers use both

Comment: Just because you can - doesn't mean you should. jQuery is used to make working with JS easier. It's used for making your code cleaner, cross-browser compatible, etc...

Comment: My main problem with your solution is that you are suggesting inconsistent coding styles.

Comment: @Lix Jquery is meant for those who are beginners in native javascript. They cant write cross browser code. Coding styles vary from person to person.

Comment: You are very wrong my friend :) JavaScript developers use all sorts of plugins and frameworks to make their jobs easier (including jQuery).
I've been working with JS for almost 10 years already and I still use jQuery very very often. Coding styles vary from person to person - this is true. But they should never vary within a team or project and definitely not within one function.

Comment: @Lix I dont use jquery, I always prefer writing my own code and libraries, if i have used different coding style that doent mean my answer was wrong

Comment: The code in your answer *will work* - I'm not saying it wont. What I'm saying is that it is **my opinion** that using your code in the current context (of this question) is a bad idea as it would cause inconsistencies in code style and because it doesn't take advantage of the already included (and used) jQuery library.

Comment: That's about all that can be said here in the comment section - if you would like to continue this discussion - [feel free to join me here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39461/discussion-between-lix-and-shadow)